# Font-Awesome FA icons not appearing on hosted github pages but works on local

Tags: html, css, import, fonts

I'm currently trying to display my font-awesome icons. Currently, they're not being shown on the hosted webpages.

My header tag in my index.html is this

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Comfy House</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">


  

  <!-- custom css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script defer src="/font-awesome/js/all.js"></script>

</head>
```

And I'm calling the icon here in my navbar for example:

```
  <!-- navbar -->
  <nav class='navbar'>
    <div class='navbar-center'>
      <span class="nav-icon">
        <i class='fas fa-bars'></i>
      </span>
      <a href="index.html">
        <div class='center-logo'>
          <img src="./images/cinnamon-roll.svg" alt="store logo">
          <p>Bun Bun Bake Shop</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      

      <div class="cart-btn">
        <span class="nav-icon">
          <i class='fas fa-cart-plus'></i>
        </span>
        <div class="cart-items">0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- end of navbar -->
```

Any help that can illuminate this issue would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try importing font-awesome styles with this in your `<head>`

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

EDIT: updated example with your code.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Comfy House</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">


  

  <!-- custom css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
  
  <nav class='navbar'>
    <div class='navbar-center'>
      <span class="nav-icon">
        <i class='fa fa-bars'></i>
      </span>
      <a href="index.html">
        <div class='center-logo'>
          <img src="./images/cinnamon-roll.svg" alt="store logo">
          <p>Bun Bun Bake Shop</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      

      <div class="cart-btn">
        <span class="nav-icon">
          <i class='fa fa-cart-plus'></i>
        </span>
        <div class="cart-items">0</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```